# dual boot ubuntu/windows7 system stuck at Grub command line

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a dual boot windows7 and Ubuntu 14.0 system. It is working fine from last three years. From last few days, I was using windows and due to power failure, my system shut down unexpectedly. It returned with "grub rescue" window.

1. I have tried the commands:
   set root=(hd0,msdos1)/boot ..... so on
   (unknown file system).
2. I have also tried grub repair using live Ubuntu CD,

It resulted in "bootmgr missing" on reboot

After it I tried fixing windows bootmgr using live ubuntu CD:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

It resulted in a black screen with grub command prompt

3. After that, I have tried to boot using grub command prompt using this link:
   https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux

still left with grub screen on reboot.

4. I have also used a windows CD for system recovery but it was not listing any operating system. Used command prompt but LIST DISK command resulted in "There s no set disk to show".

However, all the data is still safe but I am stuck with grub screen.

Can anyone help me to recover my system...??

Comment: Can you change the Boot Order by accessing the CMOS?

Comment: I thave tried to but there are only three disks visible whereas I have four disks on my system.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but the boot order in your CMOS does not represent how many disks you have, but simply how many boot managers are installed.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about CMOS, but I cross checked with one of the similar workstation in my lab and that is having four hard disks. Mine is missing the one with the operating systems installed on it.